# Qual a diferença entre OracleJDK e ZuluJDK?

Tags: java, jdk

Eu estava indo instalar o Java na Oracle quando me deparei com o [ZuluJDK](https://www.azul.com/downloads/), da Azul (que a princípio pensei que era o site da linha aérea Azul), e resolvi instalá-lo para saber como é.

A instalação foi bem simples e rápida, porém, o que mais me surpreendeu foi a velocidade de compilação e execução dessa JDK, que foi nitidamente mais rápida que o da Oracle.

Sendo assim, eu gostaria de saber quais as diferenças entre um JDK e outro, vantagens e desvantagens e se o Zulu é confiável.

Comment: Algumas empresas se propõem a fornecer os binários da OpenJDK, a Azul é uma delas. Veja outras aqui: https://whichjdk.com/ O suporte às builds OpenJDK produzidas pela Azul não é gratuito, então pode interessar mais para quem trabalha com builds com suporte pago. Esse link também é interessante: https://www.azul.com/blog/what-is-openjdk/